# GFor ArrayFire, how to "index"

Tags: parallel-processing, arrayfire

Grettings, i'm starting to learn about arrayfire and parallel computing and have a question about Gfors and the seq method.

The syntax for the Gfor is  something like

```
Gfor( seq ii, N)
```

In a regular for loop, there is (usually) a int value , so inside the for i can access data in an array like V[0][i] and use that values in the computations. The question is how can i do the same ( get the integer values saved in some array ) in the GFor , obviuslly V[0][seq] not work.

Thanks for your answers  :D !!  /* sorry for my bad english */ 
 /*  edit the for is

```
for( int i = 0; i < q ; i++ ){ 
    f(span,span,i) =shift( f(span,span,i) , V[1][i] , V[0][i], 0); 
}
```

in the array V are the shifts i need for each slice.

Comment: GFOR is intended to be used with af::arrays only. You can not use it with other types of arrays.

Comment: mmmm i understand, the thing that i want to do involves the shift function for arrayfire,  Basically i want to take an slice from an array and shift it in certain amount acording to wich slice is. the code i currently have is :  `code` f(span,span,i) =shift( f(span,span,i) , V[1][i] , V[0][i], 0) , in a for. The question is how put it in a gfor ? `code` Thanks!!

Comment: I saw your other question. You can not have custom shift for each slice. It is only possible to have the same shift for all the slices because of the way it is designed right now. There is perhaps a work around. Can you put the for loop version of what you are doing with the necessary sizes and we can see if there is an alternative for it.

Comment: Hi ! and thanks again. what i have is :                                                       for( int i = 0; i < q ; i++  ){
    f(span,span,i) =shift( f(span,span,i) , V[1][i] , V[0][i], 0);
  } In the array V i have the shifts i need for each case. there is some other way to do this?

Comment: The point is that q in this case q is 9, but in the future i need to extend de size up to 27 and this is the bottleneck in my code.

Comment: Edit the original question and put the code in there please. The comments are not intended for putting code.